# Percentage Progressing Bars

Tags: jquery

I just found animation progressing bars [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mWdgz/4/)

I wonder how to add number % running for each bar while these progressing bars are loading.

Please help.  Thank you!

Here is CSS

```
    <style type='text/css'>
    .progress_container {
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:red;
    width: 460px;
}
.progress_bar {
    height:25px;
    width: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background:black;
}
.progress_container {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
}
  </style>
```

Here is JQuery

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("document").ready(function () {

    // animate the progress bar onload

    $('.progress_bar').each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: this.title
        }, 1000);
    })

});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Here is the body

```
  <div class="progress_container">
    <div class="progress_bar tip" title="98%"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress_container">
    <div class="progress_bar tip" title="58%"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress_container">
    <div class="progress_bar tip" title="28%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What seems to be the question? Is something not working? As a sidenote, **do not** quote the document in the selector.

Comment: Yes it is working and my question is: How to add number % running for each bar while these progressing bars are loading.

Comment: You should have a look at the `step` option of `animate`.

Comment: James, Please tell me more details about "step" and how to add number % running for each bar while these progressing bars are loading

Answer (score 2):

You'd use the step method for that :

```
$('.progress_bar').each(function () {
    $(this).animate(
      {
         width: this.title
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        step    : function( current ) {
                    $(this).html(parseInt(current, 10)+'%')
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mWdgz/34/)

Comment: Master! Master! That looks great!  A little bit further: How can I place number % wherever? I mean: Can we place a value of % in a `<div>` so that we can place it any where?

Comment: You can add some css to position the text. See my answer for an example. It extends slightly on what @adeneo posted here.

Comment: @Adeneo, Thank you very much! It works like a champ! Would you please explain this function `step    : function( current ) {
                        $(this).next('.prog').html(parseInt(current, 10)+'%')` I am not clear about this function.  Thank you!

Comment: It's a method that's built into jQuery's animate to let you "step" through the animation and do other things as well.

Comment: @Adeneo, I am wondering if we can do it in a circle progressing bar? What code needed to be changed?

Comment: @abcidd - Sure, you can just as easily use the numbers in the step method to update a circular progressbar, but a circular progress is not that easy to make, and you should probably search for a plugin, and most plugins will use canvas to draw the progress bar, but it can still be updated etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the percent into a title, put the value into a data element and calculate the percent, then you can easily add to it:

HTML:

```
<div class="progress_container">
    <div class="progress_bar tip" id="pb3" data-percent="28"></div>
</div>

<button id="Add">Add</button>
```

JS:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    // animate the progress bar onload
    updatePercent();
});

function updatePercent() {

    $('.progress_bar').each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: $(this).data("percent") + "%"
        }, 1000);
    })
}

$("#Add").click(function () {
    var currVal = $("#pb3").data("percent");
    $("#pb3").data("percent", currVal + 10);
    updatePercent();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mWdgz/32/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another div and add some css to position the text as you would like.

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQGgJ/)

```
<div class="progress_container">
    <div id="progress"></div>
    <div class="progress_bar tip" title="100%"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#progress {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brian! I wonder can we place the % outside of the bar? and right now I have 3 bars, but there is only one #progress!  How can we assign other 2 number % to other bars?

Comment: Check out @adeneo's updated fiddle in the comment he posted. It shows exactly how to do it. Don't forget to mark his as answer too.